# How to copy images from android cache directory to an external directory?

Tags: android, caching

I am developing an android webview app. It just shows some images and a download link. I am able to download the images using the android DownloadManager.

As the images are already cached, it will be good if somebody can suggest an option to copy the images from android cache directory instead of making a download request.

I have gone through cache directory. But I couldn't identify the cached image files using the image name in the URL.

Comment: You can tell DownloadManager where to store downloaded images and under which name.

Comment: For the rest your whole story is pretty unclear for me.

Comment: i just want to tell the download manager that, please look into the cache before you start download. If it already there in the cache, no need to download.